Are this kind of plurisubharmonic function continuous?
Let $E$ be a closed pluripolar set in $\Omega \in \mathbb{C}^n$, if $u$ is a plurisubharmonic function on $\Omega$ and continuous on $\Omega$\E, is $e^u$ a continuous function on $\Omega$?
I think the anwser is affarmitive for the Hausdorff dimension of closed pluripolar set is at most $2n-2$ and it is nowhere dense. My idea is that: For each point $a\in E$, $\lim_{z\to a}u(z)$ (could be equal to -$\infty$ or fixed constant value) exists by continuity of $u$ in  $\Omega$\E and the property of closed pluripolar set. Take $u(a)=\lim_{z\to a}u(z)$, by uniqueness of plurisubharmonic function, we know that this function is the same as the previous one. Therefore, $e^u$ is a continuous plurisubharmonic function.
Is my statement correct? I kindly request everyone's guidance.

I think you can use the example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809149/example-of-discontinuous-subharmonic-function with $\Omega=\mathbb{C}$ and $E={0}\cup{1/n \ : \ n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}}$. The function in question satisfies $u(1/n)=-\infty$ and $u(0)>-\infty$, which makes $e^u$ discontinuous.

I understand, thank you very much!

I am going to steal the idea from Example of discontinuous subharmonic function. Let us consider the function
$$ u: \mathbb{C}\supseteq B(0,2/3) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, u(z)=\sum_{n\geq 2} e^{-n} \log(\vert z -1/n \vert).  $$
We will show that $u$ is plurisubharmonic on $\Omega=B(0,2/3)$ and continuous on $\Omega \setminus E$ with $E=\{0\}\cup \{ 1/n \ : \ n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}\}$.
u is plurisubharmonic: It is easy to check that $\log(\vert z -1/n\vert)$ is plurisubharmonic on $B(0,2/3)$. Sums of plurisubharmonic functions are plurisubharmonic (as sums of upper semi-continuous, respectively subharmonic functions are upper semi-continuous, respectively subharmonic). Thus, we can write
$$ u(z) = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=2}^N e^{-n} \log(\vert z-1/n\vert), $$
i.e. as the pointwise limit of a decreasing sequence of plurisubharmonic functions, which is plurisubharmonic again (see Properties of plurisubharmonic functions).
E is closed, pluripolar set: The same argument as above tells us that the function
$$ f: B(0, 2/3) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(z) = u(z)+\log(\vert z\vert) $$
is plurisubharmonic and hence
$$ E = \{0\} \cup \{ 1/n \ : \ n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}\} = \{ z\in B(0,2/3) \ : \ f(z) = -\infty\} $$
is a complete pluripolar set (and it is obviously closed).
$u$ is continuous on $\Omega \setminus E$: This follows from the Weierstrass $M$-test and the fact that the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.
$e^u$ is not continuous: We note that $u(1/n)=-\infty$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$. However, we have
$$ u(0) = \sum_{n\geq 2} e^{-n} \log(1/n)>-\infty. $$
Thus, we have
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{u(1/n)} = 0 \neq e^{u(0)}. $$
What's the issue? The problem with your argument is that you claim that for $a\in E$ we have that $\lim_{z\rightarrow a} u(z)$ exists. We only know that $u$ is upper semi-continuous on $\Omega \setminus E$, i.e. $\limsup_{z\rightarrow a} u(z)\leq u(a)$.

I understand，I mistakenly thought that when restricted to one dimension, the closed pluripolar set was a set of discrete points. This example directly shows that the one-dimensional situation is not correct. Thank you very much!

@YaoYaoHu You're welcome.
